# Layout tools to print big GEDCOM plus pictures to posters?

Tags: gedcom, software-recommendations, tools, webtrees.net

**Background:**
I have created a family tree containing over 1100 relatives.
Therefore I used [Webtrees](https://www.webtrees.net/index.php/en/) (based on PHP+MySql, hosted on my own web server). (This is how it can look like: [Demo family tree](https://dev.webtrees.net/demo-stable/pedigree.php?rootid=i1&ged=demo))

Now I would like to print that data in some way to put it on a big free wall in my house.

My data also includes several hundred pictures of people.
Webtrees is able to export all data in the Gedcom-Format.

**Question:** Which program would be suitable to do that task? (Gedcom data => Layout program)

- If possible I prefer free software.
- I would like to convert the whole data to something like a layout program in order to adjust several things manually before converting to PDF/printing.
- Has anybody experience with the free program [yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed)?

Comment: Did you try Gramps?

Comment: No I don't know it. Do you have a link for me?

Comment: I have looked on www.gramps-project.org but it doesn't seem to have any function to export the data graphically.

Comment: Please refer to https://www.gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=Howto:_Make_a_relationship_chart After graphviz you could save your chart to any convenient graphical format

Answer (score 2):

MyHeritage's Family Tree Builder can auto-generate an ancestral chart with pctures. I made this 14" x 30" chart a few years ago, but don't remember all the options available.

[image: Ancestral Chart]

Comment: It is great link, but as I can see the mentioned program does not draw full tree, just ancestry of one particular person. So the question if one could print whole family tree (with cousins, their childs etc.) with this program or should use another.

Comment: It probably does decendancy charts as well, which will have cousins, ect.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Family Historian [here](https://www.family-historian.co.uk/) it has an everyone diagram that can be configured how you want and it will include the photos. There is a free 30 day trial so you can do it for free within the 30 days and it will import your gedcom.